# Is there a way to use a VectorstoreIndexCreator() with a huggingface cllm model? - Langchain

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, chromadb

I'm simply trying to load a document (CSV) but I would like to use a custom llm and not the openAI one.

```
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader

loader = DataFrameLoader(dataframe, page_content_column="TRANSLATED_COMMENT")
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

How can I create a VectorstoreIndexCreator() that uses, for example:

```
llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id='decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf', huggingfacehub_api_token='XXXXX')
```